# Best Strategy to Get a Refund from British Airways

Tags: refunds, british-airways

I purchased a roundtrip plane ticket from Seattle (SEA) to London (LHR) for a trip that was supposed to take place the last week of March on British Airways (BA). Unfortunately I had to cancel the plane ticket because of the Coronavirus (COVID-19). The ticket was about $1,100 USD (both ways).

After I canceled the plane ticket online through the BA portal, I received an email on March 12 from them saying I was entitled to a refund. However, I haven't received the refunded amount to my VISA credit card.

**What's the best strategy to get my refund?**

If I need to call them what's the best time to call London time (London is 8 hours ahead of where I live in the Seattle area)?

Or instead of calling them, is it better to contact them again via email through their BA website contact form (I already did this and got a stock reply from BA saying in part "I'm so sorry to disappoint you, however we’re unable to make any alterations to bookings, or cancel them, via email.").

Or finally, should I Tweet them (another option recommended by the BA website)?

I'm fine with even getting a partial refund at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Telephone numbers and addresses](https://www.britishairways.com/en-us/information/help-and-contacts/contact-us?aboutCountry=US#) page on the British Airways web site (in the big yellow box at the top):

> If your flight has been cancelled and you’re calling about a refund, or you need to speak to us directly, please call us on 877-767-7970 from within the US. Thank you for your understanding during these challenging times.

They *want* you to call them. No need to try other avenues like email or tweeting.